# Speed up the summation of values under np.arange( 1,100)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am looping through a range of numbers, and then counting stuff in a series that is less than or equal to each range member:

```
min_odds_range = np.arange( 1.01, 2.0, 0.01 )
df_result = pd.DataFrame( columns=[ 'FILLS' ], index=min_odds_range )
for mo in min_odds_range:
    df_result[ 'FILLS' ] = my_stats[ 'PRICE' ]<=mo
```

The looping code is the slowest part of my program.

How can I speed it up? I have tried broadcasting, using the code below, but it gives me a NotImplemented exception:

```
runner_stats[ 'MIN_ODDS' ].lt( pd.DataFrame( np.arange( 1.0, 2.0, 0.1 ) ) )
```

Comment: It sounds like you could use `numpy.searchsorted`, but from your code it is not clear what exactly you try to do 1) The loop doesn't work 2) In the second code the variable names are different. It would also be very helpful if you could supply very small example input and output.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your code generates a dataframe df_result with one column 'FILLS' which then gets overwritten 10 times. Only the last iteration of your for loop actually does anything to your dataset.

This code will do the same thing, without the loop. I'm pretty sure you have missed something out in your logic though.

```
min_odds_range = np.arange( 1.01, 2.0, 0.01 )
df_result = pd.DataFrame( columns=[ 'FILLS' ], index=min_odds_range )
df_result[ 'FILLS' ] = my_stats[ 'PRICE' ] <= 2.0
```

If you could you provide some sample data for my_stats and tell us what your objective is, it would be much easier to help you out.